# Mendelson AS2 MDN issue

Tags: edi, b2b

I am establishing a new AS2 connection for a customer, but I'm having a problem with MDN sending. They report not getting the MDN.

I have this in the log :

> [14:35:43] mendelson_opensource_AS2-1521470143682-4@eg: Préparer la connexion MDN sortante vers "http://testas2.mendelson-e-c.com:8080/as2/HttpReceiver", connexions actives: 1/5.
>
> [14:35:43] mendelson_opensource_AS2-1521470143682-4@eg: Envoi d'un MDN asynchrone vers http://XXXXXXXXXX/as2/HttpReceiver.
>   [14:35:47] mendelson_opensource_AS2-1521470143682-4@eg: Message envoyé avec succès (HTTP 200); 3,30 KB transféré en 3,32s [0,99 KB/s].
>
> [14:35:47] mendAS2-1521470142708-1961@eg: Succès de la communication AS2, le contenu 1 a été déplacé vers "/home/mendelson/messages/e/inbox/g/DELINS.18031915353514355".

I don't know where I can delete this in the configuration : "http://testas2.mendelson-e-c.com:8080/as2/HttpReceiver"

Comment: Hi there, did you solve it out? I stuck on the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi, nope, I'm still having this issue, I think I'd try an older version of mendelson, I'm using the latest to this date

Comment: @TheSM Could you share the configurations of your station (local station) and partner (remote station) on Mendelson, please?